# MVC application issue with www prefix

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I have an MVC application on a remote server, with IIS 7 and ASP.NET 4.0 . My issue is that when i wright on the address bar domain.com the site loads correctly with now issues. But when  i wright down www.domain.com the site loads a white page, no content and no errors on it. Have tried everything. If i make a redirect rule from www.domain.com to doamin.com it works, but i need to add the www prefix infront of the url. Thanks in advance. I have added a rule rewrite to the web.config file, it redirects correctly the site but still nothing is loaded.

Comment: Maybe there is some error information in the IIS logs?

Comment: nope no errors on the iis logs..

Answer (score 0):

What bindings have you made in your IIS to the website? In our IIS we binded both www.domain.com and domain.com

Comment: Hello, i have both bindings to the same application on IIS, but wwhen i hit www.domain.com it just returns that white page, no errors nothing.